# Cómo puedo hacerlo más rápido?

Tags: c++, algoritmos, c++17

**Descripción**
Tienes dos amigos. A ambos quieres regalarles varios números enteros como obsequio. A tu primer amigo quieres regalarle C1 enteros y a tu segundo amigo quieres regalarle C2 enteros. No satisfecho con eso, también quieres que todos los regalos sean únicos, lo cual implica que no podrás regalar el mismo entero a ambos de tus amigos.

Además de eso, a tu primer amigo no le gustan los enteros que son divisibles por el número primo X. A tu segundo amigo no le gustan los enteros que son divisibles por el número primo Y. Por supuesto, tu no le regalaras a tus amigos números que no les gusten.

Tu objetivo es encontrar el mínimo número V, de tal modo que puedas dar los regalos a tus amigos utilizando únicamente enteros del conjunto 1, 2, 3, …, V. Por supuesto, tú podrías decidir no regalar algunos enteros de ese conjunto.

Un número entero positivo mayor a 1 es llamado primo si no tiene divisores enteros positivos además del 1 y el mismo.

**Entrada**
Una línea que contiene cuatro enteros positivos C1,C2, X, Y. Se garantiza que  X y Y son números primos.

**Salida**
Una línea. Un entero que representa la respuesta al problema.

**Mi código es el siguiente:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int c1, c2, x=2, y=2;
    int v = 0,n=1,aux=0;
    cin >> c1 >> c2 >> x >> y;

    while(c1 > 0 || c2 > 0){
        if(n % x != 0 ){
            c1--;
            v++;
        } else if(n % y != 0){
            c2--;
            v++;
        }
        n++;
    }

    cout<<v<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Los detalles y el problema en específico deben ir _en_ la pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Partiendo del caso base, vamos a medir el tiempo que tarda en resolver un problema:

```
void test()
{
    int c1, c2, x=2, y=2;
    int v = 0,n=1,aux=0;
    std::cin >> c1 >> c2 >> x >> y;

    while(c1 > 0 || c2 > 0){
        if(n % x != 0 ){
            c1--;
            v++;
        } else if(n % y != 0){
            c2--;
            v++;
        }
        n++;
    }

    std::cout<<v<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    test();

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Time: "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()  / 1000.0
              << " ms\n";
}
```

Así, ante la entrada

```
300000000 300000000 2 3
```

Este programa tarda unos 2437.13 ms

Ahora vamos con las posibles optimizaciones:

**Reducir los condicionales**

Cuántos más condicionales tengas en un código, más lento será el mismo.

En tu caso, el bucle principal evalúa dos variables diferentes en cada iteración. Dado que esa comprobación se evalúa muchísimas veces, parece buena idea simplificarla.

El bucle realmente tiene que ejecutarse hasta que se encuentren `c1+c2` números, por lo que si precalculamos ese total, nos estaremos ahorrando una comparación por iteración.

Veamos:

```
void test1()
{
    int c1, c2, x=2, y=2;
    int v = 0, n=1;

    std::cin >> c1 >> c2 >> x >> y;

    int total = c1 + c2;
    while(total > 0){
        if(c1 > 0 && n % x != 0 ){
            total--;
            c1--;
        } else if(n % y != 0){
            total--;
        }
        n++;
    }

    std::cout<<(n-1)<<std::endl;
}
```

Bajo estas condiciones el programa nos arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Time: 1798.23 ms
```

No está mal, hemos corregido un error al contar el resultado a devolver y encima ahora tarda unas 6 décimas menos

**Precalcular resultados**

No hace falta estar en cada iteración haciendo divisiones para ver si dos números son divisibles ... las divisiones son terriblemente lentas de ejecutar.

Lo que puedes hacer en este caso es precalcular cual va a ser el siguiente número prohibido para cada amigo. Esto te permite reemplazar una costosa división que se ejecuta en cada iteración por una suma que además se realiza ocasionalmente

```
int c1, c2, x=2, y=2;
int v = 0, n=1;

std::cin >> c1 >> c2 >> x >> y;
int avoid_x = x;
int avoid_y = y;

int total = c1 + c2;
while(total){
    if(c1 > 0 && n != avoid_x ){
        total--;
        c1--;
        if (n == avoid_y)
            avoid_y += y;
    } else {
        avoid_x += x;
        if(n != avoid_y) {
            total--;
        } else {
            avoid_y += y;
        }
    }
    n++;
}

std::cout<<(n-1)<<std::endl;
```

Con este algoritmo ahora obtenemos la siguiente salida:

```
Time: 0.029 ms
```

Fíjate que con este cambio el código es unas 10k veces más rápido que la versión original. Y encima es capaz de calcular mejores resultados.

Una última corrección: Hay que ordenar los valores de `x` e `y`. El número más pequeño debería estar en la `x` y el motivo es que el algoritmo da prioridad a este número sobre `y`. ¿Y qué importancia tiene eso? Bueno, cuanto más pequeño sea el número, con más frecuencia aparecerán numeros divisibles. Si dejas el número más pequeño para el final, el valor de `v` que obtengas será más grande:

Se ve mejor con un ejemplo. Vamos a comparar las secuencias que se obtienen ante dos entradas invertidas

```
7 4 2 3               4 7 3 2

1 x                   1 x
2 y                   2 x
3 x                   3 y
4 y                   4 x
5 x                   5 x
6                     6 
7 x                   7 y
8 y                   8 
9 x                   9 y
10 y                  10
11 x                  11 y
12                    12
13 x                  13 y
                      14
                      15 y
                      16
                      17 y
```

Como ves, tratar el número más pequeño en segundo lugar no es buena idea. La complejidad aquí es que este resultado también se ve afectado por el número de elementos a añadir a cada conjunto. Si el número más pequeño pertenece a un conjunto sensiblemente más pequeño, entonces lo más óptimo es tratarlo en segundo lugar. Queda en tu mano analizar bajo qué condiciones conviene invertir los números `x` e `y`.

Comment: Cuidado. **ms** significa milisegundos (milésima parte de un segundo). Tu estás usando microsegundos (millonésima parte de un segundo) y se escribe como **µs**.

Comment: calculo microsegundos... pero divido entre 1000, lo que me da milisegundos

Answer (score 0):

Una solución suponiendo que `V <= L` es

Usar una búsqueda binaria para determinar el `V` más pequeño tal que el conjunto `[1...V]` cumpla con las condiciones del problema.

```
// El limite inferior es claramente la suma de numeros que queremos entregar
int l = C1 + C2;
// El limite superior es un valor arbitrario lo suficientemente grande
int r = L;

while (l < r) {
   int m = (l + r) / 2;
   
   // f(a) es una subrutina que devuelve true si el rango [1..a] contiene 
   // un subconjunto que cumple con las condiciones del problema.
   bool esValido = f(m);

   if (!esValido) {
       l = m + 1;
   } else {
       r = m;
   }
}

return l;
```

A este punto, tendríamos una complejidad de `O(log(L - (C1 + C2) + 1) * T(f))` donde `T(f)` corresponde a la complejidad de `f(a)`

La parte más interesante radica en la subrutina `f`, donde el problema se reduce a determinar si dado un rango de números, es posible escoger un subconjunto de tamaño `C1 + C2` del que se puedan crear dos subconjuntos adicionales `A` y `B` tal que `A` no contiene ningún número divisible por `X` y similarmente `B` no contiene ningún número divisible por `Y`.

Una observación clave es darse cuenta que los únicos números que no se podrían regalar son los que sean divisibles por ambos `X` y `Y`. De lo contrario, si el número no es divisible por `X`, se lo das a la persona que no le gusten los números que sean divisibles por `Y`. De manera similar, si el número no es divisible por `Y`, se lo das a la persona que no le gusten los números que sean divisibles por `X`.

Asumiendo que `X` y `Y` son números primos distintos, basta con multiplicar ambos números para encontrar el mínimo común múltiplo. Luego, la cantidad de números en el rango `[1..a]` que son divisibles tanto por `X` y `Y` son los múltiplos del mínimo común múltiplo de `X` y `Y`, lo que se puede calcular como

```
int cantidadDivisiblesPorXyY = floor(a/(X*Y));
```

Otra observación importante es notar que tenemos que confirmar que la cantidad de números restantes no solo debe ser mayor que `C1 + C2`, sino que también debe haber por lo menos `C1` números que no sean divisibles por `X` asumiendo que `C1 >= C2`

```
int cantidadDivisiblesPorX = floor(a/X);
```

Por lo que la subrutina f terminaría siendo

```
bool f(int a) {
    return a - floor(a/(X*Y)) >= C1 + C2
        && a - floor(a/X) >= C1;
}
```

Como se puede observar la complejidad de `f` es `O(1)`, por lo que finalmente nuestro algoritmo tiene un complejidad de `O(log(L - (C1 + C2) + 1))`.

Cabe mencionar que tu solución `greedy` no es del todo correcta, en primer lugar supongo que tu intención fue retornar `n - 1` y no `v` según la descripción que has dado del problema. En cualquier caso, un contraejemplo es

```
C1 = 3;
C2 = 3;
X = 2;
y = 3;
```

Tu algoritmo retorna 8 en este caso porque hace lo siguiente

```
C1 -> [1, 3, 5, 7]
C2 -> [2, 4, 8]
```

Cuando realmente la solución óptima es

```
C1 -> [1, 3, 5]
C2 -> [2, 4, 7]
```

Espero haya sido de ayuda